# How does Time Machine deal with hard links

Tags: macos, time-machine

If I create multiple hard links to the same file on my system, will Time Machine detect it and make only one physical copy of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Repeating experiment with creating hard linked file and backing it up using time machine gives different result in 2024. Both time machine have the files still hardlinked and restoring the files preserves hard links. Tested for backup of APFS to APFS, APFS to HFS+ and HFS+ to HFS+.

### Original answer from 2010

Little experiment (creating dir, copying file there as `a.data` and creating link using `ln a.data b.data`) gave me joyless result: Time Machine doesn't care about hard links, in backup there where two separate files with link count of 1. Time Machine cares only about its own file/folder hard links.

Comment: OUCH! I literally have 200GB of files hardlinked (for organization purposes) where I can easily have 5-10 copies of the same file, but only 1TB of back up space.  So... I literally cannot use Apple's own recommended backup method because I'm using hard links?!

Comment: @Michael Unless you can use symlinks instead of hardlinks at least for part of files

Comment: I can't use soft links because of other issues (for instance OS X won't correctly render the icon of a symlink to the item it points to, instead defaulting to a blank "symlink" icon.)

Comment: Are you certain about this? I just restored Time Machine files, and my hard links were restored properly. Perhaps this has changed in ten years?

Comment: @JanSteinman You are right, I did repeat the experiment and got different result

Answer (score 0):

It will create four copies of those files!

To find and eradicate hard links maybe checkout DupeGuru. It can find dupes, including hard links, then delete, or replace with hard links, or symlinks.

Comment: This is not a solution. The shame is still on Apple.